# AIDE Won't Build App Stuck on "Running AADT" Stage

Tags: android

I've moved an app to mmy device so that AIDE can build it and so I can install but it is stuck at the AAPT stage. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Menu] -> More -> Settings -> Build & Run -> Dexer Optimizations. If it is checked, it can take a lot longer, I believe. I tried building the HelloWorld app template and I just forced it to quit building afer waiting several minutes. After I unchecked Dexer Optimizations, it only took a few seconds to build. FYI I'm using an 800MHz Android 2.3.6 phone.